# Function for summing up minutes across time windows

Tags: r

I am creating the function that sums up the difference between `time_1` and `time_2` distributed across time windows (from 8 till 9, from 9 till 10).

This is my sample data (please notice that `time_2` is always greater than `time_1`):

```
time_1 = c("08:20", "08:58", "09:30") 
time_2 = c("08:50", "09:20", "09:48") 
df = data.frame(time_1, time_2)
```

I've written the following function (it's not finished yet):

```
getTimePerIntervals <- function(df) {
  time_1_hour = as.numeric(substr(df$time_1,1,2))
  time_1_minutes = as.numeric(substr(df$time_1,4,5))
  time_2_hour = as.numeric(substr(df$time_2,1,2))
  time_2_minutes = as.numeric(substr(df$time_2,4,5))

  for (row in data_frame(time_1_hour,time_1_minutes,time_2_hour,time_2_minutes)){
    wt_8 = 0:
    wt_9 = 0
    if (row['time_1_hour']==8 & row['time_2_hour']==8)
    {
      wt_8 = row['time_2_minutes'] - row['time_1_minutes']
    }
    else if (row['time_1_hour']==9 & row['time_2_hour']==9)
    {
      wt_9 = row['time_2_minutes'] - row['time_1_minutes']
    }
    else if (row['time_1_hour']==8 & row['time_2_hour']==9)
    {
      wt_8 = (60 - row['time_1_hour'])
      wt_9 = row['time_1_minutes']
  }
# how to put wt_8 and wt_9 as columns of df?
df    
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. How to convert `wt_8` and `wt_9` to columns of `df`? Here `wt_8`
   means a time window from 8 to 9, and `wt_9` means a time window from
   9 to 10.(PLEASE NOTICE THAT I WANT TO HAVE THESE VARIABLES, NOT JUST
   OVERALL TIME DIFFERENCE)
2. Is there any more flexible way to do the same thing? For instance, imagine that the number of time windows is greater than 2, then maybe it is better to apply "less-manual" approach...

Comment: I don't have time to post a proper response currently, but look at using foverlaps from data.table. You can create a data.table of time intervals and join that with another and summarise. I'll post if this is not answered nicely when i wake up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a direct approach.

```
time_1 = c("08:20", "08:58", "09:30") 
time_2 = c("08:50", "09:20", "09:48") 
df = data.frame(time_1, time_2)
time_1_hour = as.numeric(substr(df$time_1,1,2))
time_1_minutes = as.numeric(substr(df$time_1,4,5))
time_2_hour = as.numeric(substr(df$time_2,1,2))
time_2_minutes = as.numeric(substr(df$time_2,4,5))

window_names <- seq(min(time_1_hour), max(time_2_hour))
window_names <- paste(window_names,"-", window_names+1, sep="")
window_diffs <- matrix(rep(0, length(window_names)*nrow(df)), ncol=length(window_names))
colnames(window_diffs) <- window_names

for (i in seq.int(length(time_1_hour)))  {
    # first hour
    if(time_1_hour[i] < time_2_hour[i]) {
        wname <- paste(time_1_hour[i], "-", time_1_hour[i]+1, sep="")
        window_diffs[i, wname] <- 60 - time_1_minutes[i]
    }

    # full hours, not tested
    if(time_1_hour[i]+1 <= time_2_hour[i]-1) {
        wnames <- seq(time_1_hour[i]+1, time_2_hour[i]-1)
        wnames <- paste(wnames, "-", wnames+1, sep="")
        window_diffs[i, wnames] <- 60
    }

    # last hour
    if(time_1_hour[i] <= time_2_hour[i]) wname <- paste(time_2_hour[i], "-", time_2_hour[i]+1, sep="")
    if(time_1_hour[i] == time_2_hour[i] && time_1_minutes[i] < time_2_minutes[i]) 
        window_diffs[i, wname] <- time_2_minutes[i] - time_1_minutes[i]
    if(time_1_hour[i] < time_2_hour[i]) 
        window_diffs[i, wname] <- time_2_minutes[i]
}

df <- cbind(df, window_diffs)
return(df)
```

I believe this could be improved in terms of speed.

Comment: the thing is that I need to save time differences across time windows... not just the overall time difference. for instance, if `time_1` is equal to `08:58` and `time_2` - `09:20`, then `wt_8` is `2` minutes, and `wt_9` is `20` minutes. So, I want to have variables `wt_8`, `wt_9`, etc. that will store corresponding time differences, where `wt_9` means the time window from 8 to 9, and `wt_9` means time window from 9 to 10, etc.